# How do you define the gradient of a map $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is an arbitrary inner product space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f$ is a differentiable map from the inner product space $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. How is the gradient of $f$ (at some point $v$) defined?

For a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the typical treatment of multivariable calculus defines the gradient as the transpose of the Jacobian of $f$, and the interpretation is that $\nabla f$ is the direction of (local) steepest increase.

Is there anything wrong with just using
$$\nabla f(v) := \text{argmax}_{||h|| = 1} Df(v)h$$
as a *definition* of the gradient in the general case?

Comment: Is $V$ really an arbitrary inner product space? If $V$ can be infinite-dimensional and incomplete the situation can become complicated. See examples like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2802398/473276), in which case there is actually no direction of steepest increase (but there will be if you pass to the completion..)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I meant finite dimensional. Honestly I just want to understand how you formally define the gradient of a real-valued function of a matrix.

Comment: OK. GReyes' answer below is a good one. The point is that any linear function $V \to \Bbb R$ is given by taking the inner product with some (unique) fixed vector in $V$. This is (a special case of) the Riesz representation theorem. Your argmax construction has a small problem which is that the argmax isn't always unique. (What happens when $f = 0$?). In your case there really isn't anything stopping you from using the usual definition of gradient. You can forget about the fact that they're matrices and pretend they are vectors in $\Bbb R^{mn}$ instead, with the usual standard basis!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you. If I wanted to choose an appropriate inner product on $\text{Mat}(m, n)$, so that GReyes' definition of the gradient coincides with what I'd get if I "flattened" all of the matrices like you say, which would I choose? Would I choose $\langle A, B \rangle := \text{Tr}(AB^T)$?

Comment: Yes - the standard basis of "matrices with a single entry which is a $1$ and all other entries are $0$" is orthonormal with respect to the inner product $\mathrm{Tr}(AB^T)$. So therefore if you flatten the matrices, the inner product structure is just the usual dot product on $\Bbb R^{mn}$. In other words, the flattening is an isometric isomorphism of inner product spaces. If you write out $\mathrm{Tr}(AB^T)$ you should actually see that it's just the sum over products of corresponding entries of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your map is differentiable say at $a\in V$, it means that
$$
f(a+h)=f(a)+\partial f(a)(h)+o(h)\qquad \textrm{as  } h\to 0
$$
where $\partial f(a)$ is an element of the dual space $V^*$, acting on $h$. Since your space has a Euclidean structure, you can identify $V^*$ with $V$ in such a way that
$$
\partial f(a)(h)=\langle u(a),h\rangle,
$$
for some vector $u(a)\in V$. It is this vector the one that we call gradient.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask two questions?
1. How can you prove that your definition of the gradient gives the direction of steepest ascent?
2. Can you suggest a reference for this? Do I need to learn more linear algebra? Is this differential geometry?

Comment: If $h$ is any unit vector, you have $\langle u(a),h\rangle\le \|u(a)\|$ by Cauchy-Schwartz. The equality is achieved when $h=u(a)/\|u(a\|$, which is the direction of the gradient.

Comment: This is linear algebra. In differential geometry you have a tangent space at each point and the same idea applies locally.

Comment: Could you please suggest a book? Linear Algebra Done Right has Dual Spaces but no mention of gradients.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "identify" $V^*$ with $V$? Does this mean there is an isomorphism between the two?

Comment: Yes, $\Phi:V^*\to V$. Any element $l\in V^*$ can be identified with a vector, $u=\Phi(v)$ in such a way that $l(x)=\langle u,x\rangle$ for all $x\in V$. In the infinite-dimensional case this is called Riesz representation theorem, but it is clearly true in finite dimensions. The construction of $\Phi$ goes like this: given $l$, the kernel is a $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace. Then $u=\Phi(l)$ is a vector in the orthogonal complement (which is one-dimensional). Your linear function is just a scalar multiple of the (scalar) projection onto the orthogonal complement of the kernel.

Comment: I don't know the book you mention. I recommend you read chapter 7 of Arnold's book "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics". There you can learn in a few pages what gradients, curls and divergences are and their relations to (antisymmetric) linear forms.

Comment: From the same book you can learn more Mathematics (and, more importantly, Mechanics) than from dozens of other standard books.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and follow-ups, and for the recommendation.

Comment: Izak van Dongen's comment on the need of completeness is an important one in infinite dimensions. Irrelevant in the finite-dimensional case.